# GLSL - Error: output out_var_TEXCOORD6 location or component conflict with others

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am using Unreal Engine developping an Android Game.

There is an GLSL link error in andorid.

```
[2023.04.27-13.53.51:254][660]LogRHI: Display: Encountered a new graphics PSO: 633165849
[2023.04.27-13.53.51:254][660]LogRHI: Display: New Graphics PSO (633165849)
[2023.04.27-13.53.51:254][660]LogRHI: Display: 226DDC872FBEEDE643FAFD7F8267C3BC6ABA86F9,61341BB303F838D1183143A82A873E7E6823021B,0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,<0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 15 0 1 0 0 1 0 15 0 1 0 0 1 0 15 0 1 0 0 1 0 15 0 1 0 0 1 0 15 0 1 0 0 1 0 15 0 1 0 0 1 0 15 0 0>,<0.000000 0.000000 2 0 0 0 0>,<1 1 0 7 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 255 255>,1,12,12,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,<0 0 3 0 12 0>,<1 0 5 1 8 0>,<1 4 5 2 8 0>,<2 0 7 3 0 0>,<3 0 13 4 12 0>,<3 8 12 5 12 0>,<3 8 12 6 12 0>,<3 8 12 7 12 0>,<3 8 12 15 12 0>,<4 0 4 8 16 1>,<5 0 13 9 24 1>,<5 8 13 10 24 1>,<5 16 13 11 24 1>,<6 0 14 12 8 1>,<0 0 0 0 0 0>,<0 0 0 0 0 0>,<0 0 0 0 0 0>
[2023.04.27-13.53.51:285][660]LogRHI: Error: Failed to link program. Current total programs: 50 program binary bytes, last gl error 0x0, drvalloc 432248
  log:
Error: output out_var_TEXCOORD6 location or component conflict with others.
```

The vertex shader is

```c
#version 320 es


#define INTERFACE_BLOCK(Pos, Interp, Modifiers, Semantic, PreType, PostType) layout(location=Pos) Modifiers Semantic { PreType PostType; }
//  M_Tree_leaves/Default/FInstancedStaticMeshVertexFactory/TShadowDepthVSVertexShadowDepth_OutputDepth/0/ShadowDepthVertexShader.usf:Main
#define HLSLCC_DX11ClipSpace 1 


invariant gl_Position;

#define View_GameTime (vc0_h[8].x)
#define View_RelativePrevPreViewTranslation (vc0_h[7].xyz)
#define View_RelativePreViewTranslation (vc0_h[6].xyz)
#define View_RelativeWorldCameraOrigin (vc0_h[5].xyz)
#define View_ViewTilePosition (vc0_h[4].xyz)
#define View_ViewToTranslatedWorld (mat4(vc0_h[0 + 0].xyzw,vc0_h[0 + 1].xyzw,vc0_h[0 + 2].xyzw,vc0_h[0 + 3].xyzw))
#define SPIRV_Cross_CombinedMaterial_Texture2D_0Material_Texture2D_0Sampler vs0
uniform highp vec4 vc0_h[9];


#define Primitive_RelativeWorldToLocal (mat4(vc1_h[5 + 0].xyzw,vc1_h[5 + 1].xyzw,vc1_h[5 + 2].xyzw,vc1_h[5 + 3].xyzw))
#define Primitive_LocalToRelativeWorld (mat4(vc1_h[1 + 0].xyzw,vc1_h[1 + 1].xyzw,vc1_h[1 + 2].xyzw,vc1_h[1 + 3].xyzw))
#define Primitive_TilePosition (vc1_h[0].xyz)
#define Primitive_Flags (vc1_u[0].x)
uniform highp vec4 vc1_h[9];
uniform uvec4 vc1_u[1];


#define MobileShadowDepthPass_bClampToNearPlane (vc2_h[9].x)
#define MobileShadowDepthPass_ShadowParams (vc2_h[8])
#define MobileShadowDepthPass_ViewMatrix (mat4(vc2_h[4 + 0].xyzw,vc2_h[4 + 1].xyzw,vc2_h[4 + 2].xyzw,vc2_h[4 + 3].xyzw))
#define MobileShadowDepthPass_ProjectionMatrix (mat4(vc2_h[0 + 0].xyzw,vc2_h[0 + 1].xyzw,vc2_h[0 + 2].xyzw,vc2_h[0 + 3].xyzw))
uniform highp vec4 vc2_h[10];


#define Material_PreshaderBuffer_6 (vc3_h[2])
#define Material_PreshaderBuffer_5 (vc3_h[1])
#define Material_PreshaderBuffer_4 (vc3_h[0])
uniform highp vec4 vc3_h[3];


#define _Globals_InstancingOffset (vu_h[1])
#define _Globals_InstancingFadeOutParams (vu_h[0])
uniform highp vec4 vu_h[2];


uniform highp sampler2D SPIRV_Cross_CombinedMaterial_Texture2D_0Material_Texture2D_0Sampler;

layout(location = 0) in vec4 in_var_ATTRIBUTE0;
layout(location = 1) in mediump vec3 in_var_ATTRIBUTE1;
layout(location = 2) in mediump vec4 in_var_ATTRIBUTE2;
layout(location = 3) in mediump vec4 in_var_ATTRIBUTE3;
layout(location = 4) in vec2 in_var_ATTRIBUTE4;
layout(location = 8) in vec4 in_var_ATTRIBUTE8;
layout(location = 9) in mediump vec4 in_var_ATTRIBUTE9;
layout(location = 10) in mediump vec4 in_var_ATTRIBUTE10;
layout(location = 11) in mediump vec4 in_var_ATTRIBUTE11;
layout(location = 12) in vec4 in_var_ATTRIBUTE12;
#ifdef GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters
#define SPIRV_Cross_BaseInstance gl_BaseInstanceARB
#else
uniform int SPIRV_Cross_BaseInstance;
#endif
layout(location = 0) out mediump vec4 out_var_TEXCOORD10;
layout(location = 1) out mediump vec4 out_var_TEXCOORD11;
layout(location = 2) flat out vec4 out_var_COLOR1;
layout(location = 3) out vec4 out_var_TEXCOORD0[1];
layout(location = 4) flat out mat3x4 out_var_INSTANCE_WORLD_TO_LOCAL;
layout(location = 5) out float out_var_TEXCOORD6;
layout(location = 6) out vec3 out_var_TEXCOORD7;

mat4 _149;
mat3 _150;
vec3 _151;

void main()
{
    mat4 _203 = _149;
    _203[0] = vec4(Primitive_RelativeWorldToLocal[0].xyz, 0.0);
    mat4 _209 = _203;
    _209[1] = vec4(Primitive_RelativeWorldToLocal[1].xyz, 0.0);
    mat4 _215 = _209;
    _215[2] = vec4(Primitive_RelativeWorldToLocal[2].xyz, 0.0);
    mat4 _221 = _215;
    _221[3] = vec4(Primitive_RelativeWorldToLocal[3].xyz, 1.0);
    mediump vec3 _48 = cross(in_var_ATTRIBUTE2.xyz, in_var_ATTRIBUTE1) * in_var_ATTRIBUTE2.w;
    mediump mat3 _60 = _150;
    _60[0] = cross(_48, in_var_ATTRIBUTE2.xyz) * in_var_ATTRIBUTE2.w;
    mediump mat3 _61 = _60;
    _61[1] = _48;
    mediump mat3 _62 = _61;
    _62[2] = in_var_ATTRIBUTE2.xyz;
    mat3 _228 = mat3(in_var_ATTRIBUTE9.xyz, in_var_ATTRIBUTE10.xyz, in_var_ATTRIBUTE11.xyz);
    vec3 _229 = vec4(Primitive_LocalToRelativeWorld[0].xyz, 0.0).xyz;
    vec3 _230 = vec4(Primitive_LocalToRelativeWorld[1].xyz, 0.0).xyz;
    vec3 _231 = vec4(Primitive_LocalToRelativeWorld[2].xyz, 0.0).xyz;
    mat3 _233 = mat3(_229, _230, _231) * _228;
    mediump mat3 _63 = _233;
    _63[0] = normalize(_233[0]);
    mediump mat3 _64 = _63;
    _64[1] = normalize(_233[1]);
    mediump mat3 _65 = _64;
    _65[2] = normalize(_233[2]);
    mediump mat3 _57 = _65 * _62;
    float _237 = trunc(in_var_ATTRIBUTE9.w * 0.00390625);
    vec3 _243 = in_var_ATTRIBUTE8.xyz + (_228 * _Globals_InstancingOffset.xyz);
    vec3 _256 = ((Primitive_TilePosition + (-View_ViewTilePosition)) * 2097152.0) + (vec4(Primitive_LocalToRelativeWorld[3].xyz, 1.0).xyz + View_RelativePreViewTranslation);
    vec4 _272 = vec4(0.0);
    _272.x = 1.0 - clamp((length(vec4((((_243.xxx * _229) + (_243.yyy * _230)) + (_243.zzz * _231)) + _256, 1.0).xyz) - _Globals_InstancingFadeOutParams.x) * _Globals_InstancingFadeOutParams.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    float _280 = (_Globals_InstancingFadeOutParams.z * _237) + (_Globals_InstancingFadeOutParams.w * (1.0 - _237));
    vec4 _281 = _272;
    _281.y = _280;
    vec4 _282 = _281;
    _282.z = 0.0;
    vec4 _286 = vec4(in_var_ATTRIBUTE9.xyz, 0.0);
    vec4 _290 = vec4(in_var_ATTRIBUTE10.xyz, 0.0);
    vec4 _294 = vec4(in_var_ATTRIBUTE11.xyz, 0.0);
    vec4 _298 = vec4(in_var_ATTRIBUTE8.xyz, 1.0);
    mat4 _299 = mat4(_286, _290, _294, _298);
    vec4 _300 = _299 * in_var_ATTRIBUTE0;
    vec3 _309 = (((_300.xxx * _229) + (_300.yyy * _230)) + (_300.zzz * _231)) + _256;
    vec4 _314 = vec4(_309, 1.0) * _280;
    vec3 _315 = _314.xyz;
    vec3 _316 = _286.xyz;
    vec3 _318 = _151;
    _318.x = dot(_316, _316);
    vec3 _319 = _290.xyz;
    vec3 _321 = _318;
    _321.y = dot(_319, _319);
    vec3 _322 = _294.xyz;
    vec3 _324 = _321;
    _324.z = dot(_322, _322);
    vec3 _325 = inversesqrt(_324);
    float _326 = _325.x;
    vec3 _328 = _316 * (_326 * _326);
    mat4 _330 = _299;
    _330[0] = vec4(_328.x, _328.y, _328.z, _286.w);
    float _331 = _325.y;
    vec3 _333 = _319 * (_331 * _331);
    mat4 _335 = _330;
    _335[1] = vec4(_333.x, _333.y, _333.z, _290.w);
    float _336 = _325.z;
    vec3 _338 = _322 * (_336 * _336);
    mat4 _340 = _335;
    _340[2] = vec4(_338.x, _338.y, _338.z, _294.w);
    mat4 _342 = _340;
    _342[3] = vec4(vec3(0.0).x, vec3(0.0).y, vec3(0.0).z, _298.w);
    mat4 _343 = transpose(_342);
    vec4 _350 = _343 * vec4(-_298.xyz, 0.0);
    mat4 _353 = _343;
    _353[3] = vec4(_350.x, _350.y, _350.z, _343[3].w);
    mediump vec3 _58 = _57[2];
    vec3 _505;
    do
    {
        if (_280 < 1.0)
        {
            _505 = vec3(0.0);
            break;
        }
        if ((Primitive_Flags & 16777216u) == 0u)
        {
            _505 = vec3(0.0);
            break;
        }
        vec3 _371 = normalize(vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
        vec3 _372 = vec3((View_GameTime * Material_PreshaderBuffer_4.w) * (-0.5));
        vec3 _374 = _315 - View_RelativePreViewTranslation;
        vec3 _385 = abs((fract(fract((View_ViewTilePosition * vec3(0.0009765625)) * 2097152.0) + (((_371 * _372) + (_374 * vec3(0.0009765625))) + vec3(0.5))) * vec3(2.0)) + vec3(-1.0));
        vec3 _401 = abs((fract(fract((View_ViewTilePosition * vec3(0.004999999888241291046142578125)) * 2097152.0) + ((_372 + (_374 * vec3(0.004999999888241291046142578125))) + vec3(0.5))) * vec3(2.0)) + vec3(-1.0));
        float _408 = (dot(_371, ((vec3(3.0) - (_385 * vec3(2.0))) * _385) * _385) + length(((vec3(3.0) - (_401 * vec3(2.0))) * _401) * _401)) * 6.283185482025146484375;
        vec3 _418 = textureLod(SPIRV_Cross_CombinedMaterial_Texture2D_0Material_Texture2D_0Sampler, in_var_ATTRIBUTE4, -1.0).xyz;
        vec3 _419 = _418 + vec3(0.0, 0.0, -10.0);
        vec3 _420 = vec4(cross(_371, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), _408).xyz;
        vec3 _424 = _419 + (_420 * dot(_420, _418 - _419));
        vec3 _425 = _418 - _424;
        vec3 _445 = View_ViewTilePosition - View_ViewTilePosition;
        vec3 _446 = View_RelativeWorldCameraOrigin - _374;
        float _451 = _445.x;
        float _452 = _446.x;
        float _458 = _445.y;
        float _459 = _446.y;
        float _465 = _445.z;
        float _466 = _446.z;
        vec3 _480 = vec3(inversesqrt(((((_452 * (_452 * 4.76837158203125e-07)) + (_459 * (_459 * 4.76837158203125e-07))) + (_466 * (_466 * 4.76837158203125e-07))) * 4.76837158203125e-07) + (((_451 * (_451 + (_452 * 9.5367431640625e-07))) + (_458 * (_458 + (_459 * 9.5367431640625e-07)))) + (_465 * (_465 + (_466 * 9.5367431640625e-07))))) * 4.76837158203125e-07);
        _505 = (((((_424 + ((_425 * cos(_408)) + (cross(_420, _425) * sin(_408)))) - _418) * vec3(Material_PreshaderBuffer_5.x * in_var_ATTRIBUTE3.w)) * vec3(Material_PreshaderBuffer_5.z)) + _418) * clamp(vec3(1.0) - clamp(((vec3(length((_445 * 2097152.0) + _446)) * vec3(dot(((_445 * _480) * 2097152.0) + (_446 * _480), mat3(View_ViewToTranslatedWorld[0].xyz, View_ViewToTranslatedWorld[1].xyz, View_ViewToTranslatedWorld[2].xyz) * vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)))) - vec3(24.0)) * vec3(Material_PreshaderBuffer_6.x), vec3(0.0), vec3(1.0)), vec3(0.0), vec3(1.0));
        break;
    } while(false);
    vec3 _506 = _315 + _505;
    vec4 _512 = MobileShadowDepthPass_ProjectionMatrix * vec4(_506.x, _506.y, _506.z, _314.w);
    vec4 _524;
    if ((MobileShadowDepthPass_bClampToNearPlane > 0.0) && (_512.z > _512.w))
    {
        vec4 _522 = _512;
        _522.z = 0.999998986721038818359375;
        vec4 _523 = _522;
        _523.w = 1.0;
        _524 = _523;
    }
    else
    {
        _524 = _512;
    }
    float _530 = abs(dot(vec3(MobileShadowDepthPass_ViewMatrix[0].z, MobileShadowDepthPass_ViewMatrix[1].z, MobileShadowDepthPass_ViewMatrix[2].z), _58));
    vec4 _554 = _524;
    _554.z = (1.0 - (_524.z * MobileShadowDepthPass_ShadowParams.w)) + ((MobileShadowDepthPass_ShadowParams.y * clamp((abs(_530) > 0.0) ? (sqrt(clamp(1.0 - (_530 * _530), 0.0, 1.0)) / _530) : MobileShadowDepthPass_ShadowParams.z, 0.0, MobileShadowDepthPass_ShadowParams.z)) + MobileShadowDepthPass_ShadowParams.x);
    mat4 _568 = _149;
    _568[0] = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    mat4 _569 = _568;
    _569[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    mat4 _570 = _569;
    _570[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    mat4 _575 = _570;
    _575[3] = vec4(((View_ViewTilePosition + (-Primitive_TilePosition)) * 2097152.0) + (-View_RelativePrevPreViewTranslation), 1.0);
    mat4 _577 = transpose((_353 * _221) * _575);
    mat3x4 _579 = mat3x4(vec4(0.0), vec4(0.0), vec4(0.0));
    _579[0] = _577[0];
    mat3x4 _581 = _579;
    _581[1] = _577[1];
    mat3x4 _583 = _581;
    _583[2] = _577[2];
    out_var_TEXCOORD10 = vec4(_57[0], 0.0);
    out_var_TEXCOORD11 = vec4(_58, in_var_ATTRIBUTE2.w * (((Primitive_Flags & 64u) != 0u) ? (-1.0) : 1.0));
    out_var_COLOR1 = _282;
    out_var_TEXCOORD0 = vec4[](vec4(in_var_ATTRIBUTE4.x, in_var_ATTRIBUTE4.y, vec4(0.0).z, vec4(0.0).w));
    out_var_INSTANCE_WORLD_TO_LOCAL = _583;
    out_var_TEXCOORD6 = 0.0;
    out_var_TEXCOORD7 = _506.xyz;
    gl_Position = _554;
    gl_Position.z = 2.0 * gl_Position.z - gl_Position.w;
    gl_Position.y = -gl_Position.y;
}
```

And fragment shader is

```c
#version 320 es
#define UE_MRT_FRAMEBUFFER_FETCH 1

#define INTERFACE_BLOCK(Pos, Interp, Modifiers, Semantic, PreType, PostType) layout(location=Pos) Modifiers Semantic { PreType PostType; }
//  M_Tree_leaves/Default/FInstancedStaticMeshVertexFactory/TShadowDepthPSPixelShadowDepth_NonPerspectiveCorrect/0/ShadowDepthPixelShader.usf:Main
#define HLSLCC_DX11ClipSpace 1 


precision mediump float;
precision highp int;

#define Material_PreshaderBuffer_4 (pc0_h[0])
#define SPIRV_Cross_CombinedMaterial_Texture2D_0Material_Texture2D_0Sampler ps0
uniform highp vec4 pc0_h[1];


uniform highp sampler2D SPIRV_Cross_CombinedMaterial_Texture2D_0Material_Texture2D_0Sampler;

layout(location = 0) in vec4 in_var_TEXCOORD10;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 in_var_TEXCOORD11;
layout(location = 2) flat in highp vec4 in_var_COLOR1;
layout(location = 3) in highp vec4 in_var_TEXCOORD0[1];
layout(location = 4) flat in highp mat3x4 in_var_INSTANCE_WORLD_TO_LOCAL;
layout(location = 5) in highp float in_var_TEXCOORD6;
layout(location = 6) in highp vec3 in_var_TEXCOORD7;

void main()
{
    if (((texture(SPIRV_Cross_CombinedMaterial_Texture2D_0Material_Texture2D_0Sampler, vec2(in_var_TEXCOORD0[0].x, in_var_TEXCOORD0[0].y)).w * Material_PreshaderBuffer_4.y) - 0.330078125) < 0.0)
    {
        discard;
    }
}
```

I almost cannot find any discussion about "VARIBALE location or component conflict with others"

https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-opengl-extensions-on-android.404110/ has no help.

Why this link error occurred?

Comment: Which GPU and driver version?

Comment: The OpenGLES, device paramter are here
https://opengles.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=5869

Comment: Honestly, this looks like a driver bug to me.